# How can I get imenu-list to accept mouse input?

Tags: doom, imenu

I'm using Doom in Emacs 27.2. I can call `imenu-list-smart-toggle` and I get the imenu window. If I switch to that window using the keyboard, it functions normally.

But, when the cursor is in my text editing window and I use the mouse to click on an imenu window entry, cursor focus jumps back to my editing window without any navigation occuring. I have to click on a blank area in the imenu window to switch focus to that window, and then click on the menu entry.

imenu works fine in my old (Spacemacs) setup so I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: It may be helpful to see what your mouse click is bound to when you expect imenu to react in a certain way.  Perhaps you could try `C-h k` and then your mouse click in the desired location ... aka `M-x describe-key`

Comment: ```evil-mouse-drag-region is an interactive and compiled function defined
in evil-commands.el.

Signature
(evil-mouse-drag-region START-EVENT)

Documentation
Set the region to the text that the mouse is dragged over.

Highlight the drag area as you move the mouse.
This must be bound to a button-down mouse event.

If the click is in the echo area, display the *Messages* buffer.

START-EVENT should be the event that started the drag.

Key Bindings
evil-motion-state-map <down-mouse-1>

References
evil-mouse-drag-region is unused in evil-commands.el.
```

Comment: I don't use evil, but my first inclination would be to remove that keyboard/mouse assignment to `evil-mouse-drag-region` and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: In normal emacs (or at least *my* emacs :-) ), `<mouse-1>` is bound to `mouse-drag-region` but if there is no  region, it gets translated to `<mouse-2>` which is bound to `push-button`: it seems that Doom is missing that translation. See if `<mouse-2>` is bound to `push-button` and if it is, try that button.

Comment: OK, I'll ask on the Doom channel to see how I could achieve that